# Any file type that can go over JPEG maximum resolution limit?

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg

I am trying to combine multiple JPEG file into one single long file using this command

`magick convert ..\galerry\*.jpg -gravity center -append longview.jpg`

However while combining the files, imagemagick reached the limit of 65500 pixels

Is there any file format that can store image larger than 65500 pixels with the same compression as JPEG file format?

Comment: There may be such format, but what good is it if nothing can display them? An image this big is unwieldy, it is usually split into several tiles. The [WebP format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) base image is limited to 16Kx16K, but a format extension lets you make bigger images by tiling them (up to 16Kx16K tiles...)

Comment: @xenoid I mean, I could view them directly. Heck, that's not even the reason why I need them that way. The main reason why I need them this way is for some scrolling image thingy magic (Only the height is changed). And no, I need it in a single file because some issues. The main issue I'm having is from 10 pictures the size of 1 MB has turned into 1 picture the size of 100 MB in PNG format. That's not supposed to work that way. And PNG image don't have Lossy Compression.

Comment: Try JPEG2000, by changing your output file extension to `.jp2`